# R case_when and %in%

Tags: r

what on earth am i doing wrong with this case_when statement.

I have a data frame with presidential election data. I'm trying to create a new variable for rust belt states if they belong to one of these six states - Ohio, Michigan, etc. I want to tag the rust belt states with a 1 and the others with a 0. :(

```
pres2016 <- pres2016 %>%
  mutate(rust_belt = case_when(state %in% c("OH", "MI", "PA", "WI","IN", "IL") ~ 1, !(state %in% c("OH", "MI", "PA", "WI","IN", "IL") ~ 0)))
```

I seem to get the 1 values showing up OK but then NA all the way down, the zeros don't catch at all

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The new column has 1 for each of the six states but everything that isn't a 1 is NA. The zeros don't show up in the column
This part doesn't do anything ....     ~ 0

Comment: Your parentheses aren't in the right spot. `!(state %in% c("OH", "MI", "PA", "WI","IN", "IL")` is not closed on the left-hand-side of the formula. `!(state %in% c("OH", "MI", "PA", "WI","IN", "IL")) ~ 0` will work just fine.

Comment: @thelatemail But maybe easier just to use `TRUE ~ 0` at the end, since the second logical condition is just the negation of the first one.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - that's true, but it's also good to know *why* the code doesn't work.

Comment: oh wow you're right that did work when I made it this instead:

pres2016 <- pres2016 %>%
  mutate(rust_belt = case_when(state %in% c("OH", "MI", "PA", "WI","IN", "IL") ~ 1, !(state %in% c("OH", "MI", "PA", "WI","IN", "IL")) ~ 0))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could actually just use `ifelse` here:

```
pres2016$rust_belt <- ifelse(pres2016$state %in% c("OH", "MI", "PA", "WI","IN", "IL"), 1, 0)
```

If you really want to use `case_when` here, then just provide a default option using `TRUE ~ ...`:

```
pres2016 <- pres2016 %>%
    mutate(rust_belt = case_when(state %in% c("OH", "MI", "PA", "WI","IN", "IL") ~ 1,
                                 TRUE ~ 0))
```

Comment: that ifelse works thank you that's amazing stuff.   What is the TRUE part of this case_when ... why not just   ~ 1, 0 at the end ?

Comment: The syntax for the conditions in `case_when` are a logical condition, followed by `~`, followed by a predicate value.  For the catch-all case, you can list `TRUE` _last_, which is the else case for anything not matching a rust belt state.